# Why Friday Salat is important for society? (Analyzing Friday salat from sociology perspective)

Tags: salat, jumuah

It seems that Friday Salat is an important subject in Islam. I am analyzing this event from sociology perspective and will be thankful if you share your opinions about importance of Friday Salat. Why it is so important? Why people should join it and any other opinions that help me to analyze it as an Sociologist.

**Update**

--- In some sources "unity between people" marked as an purpose:

Regarding to this item, my question is that what is difference between regular Salats and Friday Salat. With a regular Salat peoples can show the unity. for example in the Haj all branches of Islam pray a unique regular Salat.

--- In some sources "increasing Islamic-politic information between the peoples" marked as an purpose too:

Also regarding to this item, now by help of TV channels and newspaper why should we still need the Friday Salat?

--- In some sources "Increasing the friendly relation between people" marked as an purpose too:

Regarding to this item, Do holding some celebrating festivals or celebration at end of each day can not increase the friendly relation between peoples more than collecting together and talk about political events?

**It is necessary that I remark that I am analyzing this event from sociological perspective and asking this question is only for finding the real of the this big event in Islam and showing its real face and hope no one do not misunderstand my purpose of asking this questions**

Answer (score 2):

Briefly speaking, there can be several positive/constructive consequences by the attendance of the Muslims in Friday prayer (Salah-al-Jom'ah), such as:

- Making unity between people who would be led in stronger Islamic
  society
- Increasing the friendly relation between people
- Increasing the Islamic-politic information of people by the lecture   of ...

And so forth.

**But the most significant consequence is the first one as I remarked as the unity in the Islamic society.**

---

Source and free study regarding Unity:

- [islamportal.net](http://islamportal.net/search/node/unity)

Comment: regarding to the unity between people, what is diffrence between regular Salats and Friday Salat. With a regular Salat peoples can show the unity. for example in the Haj all branches of Islam pray a unique regular Salat

Comment: Also regarding to the increasing Islamic-politic information between the peoples, now by help of tv channels and newspaper why should we still need the Friday Salat?